# Jasmine Sinon Testing Methods on Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, sinon

I have this object that contains a method update.  Update calls out to another service to make the request.  I am trying to test the update method on the object.

Object:

```
user = {
  "name": "Ryan",
  "playerId": "8384238973",
  "type": "person",
  "userId": "b8bbdddd",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/myUsers/b8bbdddd"
    }
  },
  "update": function update( data ) {
    return Requests.update(user, data)
      .then(function(res){
        _.assign(user, res);
      });
  }
};
```

My tests look like the following:

```
RequestUpdate = sinon.stub(Requests, 'update').returns(q.when(updateResponse));  

var updateData = {
     name: 'Tom',
      playerId: '838423838383'
    };

var updateResponse = {
  "name": "Tom",
  "playerId": "838423838383",
  "type": "person",
  "userId": "b8bbdddd",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/myUsers/b8bbdddd"
    }
  }
};

var expectedUser = {
  "name": "Tom",
  "playerId": "838423838383",
  "type": "person",
  "userId": "b8bbdddd",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/myUsers/b8bbdddd"
    }
  },
  "update": function update( data ) {
    return Requests.update(user, data)
      .then(function(res){
        _.assign(user, res);
      });
  }
};

var updateSpy = sinon.spy(device, 'update');

updateSpy(updateData).then(function(res){
    updatedUser = res;
    dump(res) //undefined
});

scope.$digest();
expect(angular.equals(updatedUser, expectedUser)).toBe(true); //expected fale to be true
```

I keep getting the error `Expected false to be true`

Comment: Why don't you use jasmine's `toEqual` to at least get a more meaningful error: `expect(updatedUser).toEqual(expectedUser);`.

Comment: When I change it I get `expected undefined to Equal...` so I'm unsure of why my spy is returning undefined